# Matplotlib - Draw 3D line from bound to bound?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Each line is defined with start and end points (`X = [x1, x2] , Y = [y1, y2] , Z = [z1, z2]`)

I draw lines by `plot_wireframe`:

`ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color='0.75')`

Is there an out of the box function that by given that the figure bounds is known, to draw a line from bound to bound ?

[image: Example Figure]